Is it possible to make pycharm always ignore "unused import statement" errors, without disabling the unresolved references inspection as a whole?
I know that in pycharm you can get rid of "unused import statement" detection by deleting the import, or by putting # noqa after the import, or by putting # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences before the import, however neither of these is what I want. I want the error to be ignored in all files project-wide without having to put an extra comment every time. I also don't want to disable the Unused Reference inspection as whole, I only want this to apply to pycharm's detection of unused imports. I don't see any way to do this.
